# Unable display bootstrap glyphicons on emulator phone

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have created phone app with cordova and bootstrap.
My app normally display plyphicons on real device (winphone & android)
But when I run my app on emulator device It's icon is not displayed.
I don't know why?Anyone can help me?

Comment: are you using Opera to emulate?

Comment: I'm using Winphone 8.1 emulator